# pySpark: How can I get all element names in structType in arrayType column in a dataframe?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe that looks something like this:

```
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- age: string (nullable = true)
 |-- job: string (nullable = true)
 |-- hobbies: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- favorite: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- non-favorite: string (nullable = true)
```

And I'm trying to get this information:

```
['favorite', 'non-favorite']
```

However, the only closest solution I found was using the explode function with `withColumn`, but it was based on the assumption that I already know the names of the elements. But What I want to do is, without knowing the element names, I want to get the element names only with the column name, in this case 'hobbies'.
Is there a good way to get all the element names in any given column?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a given dataframe with this schema:

```
df.printSchema()

root
 |-- hobbies: array (nullable = false)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |-- favorite: string (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- non-favorite: string (nullable = false)
```

You can select the field names of the struct as:

```
struct_fields = df.schema['hobbies'].dataType.elementType.fieldNames()

# output: ['favorite', 'non-favorite']
```

Answer (score 1):

[`pyspark.sql.types.StructType.fieldnames`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.types.StructType.html#pyspark.sql.types.StructType.fieldNames) should get you what you want.

> ```
> fieldNames()
>
> Returns all field names in a list.
>
> >>> struct = StructType([StructField("f1", StringType(), True)])
> >>> struct.fieldNames()
> ['f1']
> ```

So in your case something like

```
dataframe.hobbies.getItem(0).fieldnames()
```